# php api mysql or postgresql result type specification for update post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I am getting a record from database with my PHP rest API.

```
http://myapiyrl/product/get.php?id=20
```

resut:

```
{
   "id": "20",
   "name": "laptop",
   "color": "white",
   "price": "1200"
}
```

So I want to edit this record. I am posting this record to `post.php`

```
http://myapiyrl/product/post.php

private function createUpdateQueryStringFrom($_POST){
    $attributes = array();

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        $attributes[] = " $key=$value ";

    $query_string = " UPDATE product ";
    $query_string .= " SET ";
    $query_string .= join(",", $attributes);
    $query_string .= " WHERE gid = ";
    $query_string .= $_POST["gid"];

    return $query_string;
}
```

This fucntion creates an update query string like this:

```
update product set id=20, name=laptop, color=black, price=1250 where id=20

    This gives error: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or 
near &quot;,&quot; ^name=laptop
```

Ithink this update query should be create by column types. if column is string it will between (""), if it is number not.

```
update product set id=20, name="laptop", color="black", price=1250 where id=20
```

How can I solve this problem? Can I specify types while getting from database like this:

```
{
   {"id": "20", "type": "number"}
   {"name": "laptop","type": "string"}
   {"color": "white","type": "string"}
   {"price": "1200","type": "number"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check value with `is_numeric` and add quotes accordingly:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $attributes[] = is_numeric($value) ? " $key=$value " : " $key=\"$value\" ";
```